# in the last line of my code, I can't print out the result

Tags: python

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}

students = ['lloyd', 'alice', 'tyler']

for student in students:
    print student['name']
```

---

The error reminded is the indice of str can only be integer, not str. Please help me figure out the my error

Comment: You want: `students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `students` variable is a list of 3 strings, rather than list of 3 dictionaries

Answer (score 6):

Because `students` contains Strings that just happen to be the names of students, not the student dictionaries themselves. Change:

```
students = ["lloyd", "alice", "tyler"]
```

To

```
students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]
```

Notice the lack of quotes.

Comment: Since I have defined the dictionary lloyd, I can just define the students list with lloyd without the quotes. Is my understanding right? Thank you!

Comment: When you say `lloyd = {...}`, you've created a label called `lloyd`. It's not actually quite that simple, but basically, ya. You've created a name to reference the object with, which does not require quotes to use. I recommend taking a step back and learning the Python basics if this is news to you you should understand how variables works before you start messing with dictionaries, since they require basic knowledge to use.

Comment: Sorry to interrupt you! Could you please recommend me for some books or other materials to learn some Python basics?

Comment: @Liuyang It's been quite awhile since I've written Python; I honestly can't remember exactly how I learned it. I do remember though that the Python docs  were an amazing reference. Start here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html. It's a lot to read, but a **major** part of programming is going over documentation, which is essentially an instruction manual.

Comment: @Liuyang At the *very* least, read this section: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html

Comment: @Liuyang And if you think this answer has helped you the most, please press the green check next to my answer to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You created the list `students` as a list of strings, not as a list of references.
You should edit the content from:

```
students = ["lloyd", "alice", "tyler"]
```

to using the references to the dicts created above:

```
students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]
```

Comment: if you appreciated my answer please upvote it or sign it as the best answer. cheers

Answer (score 0):

you need to take away the quotes, so that would be:`[lloyd, alice, tyler]`